# Fake path with .htaccess mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been trying for hours and can't find a solution on here that works for me.

Trying to add a fake directory to a url: Example:
http://example.com/real/ --> http://example.com/fake/real

Not having much luck with this:

```
RewriteRule ^fake/real/(.*)$ /real/$1 [L]
```

*(NOTE: Other RewriteRule's in my htaccess are working fine, for example this one):
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/about?$ about.php?lang=$1 [L]*

Comment: Where did you put this? How does it not work? What happens when you go to `example.com/fake/real/cookies`? Have you enabled mod_rewrite and set the correct `Options` for mod_rewrite to work? I am pretty sure this rule should do what you expect it to do. This question contains not enough information to answer properly.

Comment: I edited the post to add more info. This in my .htaccess file. Other rewrites are working fine, so I know mod_rewrite is functional. When I type example.com/fake/real/cookies, it just shows the home page of the site, example.com

Comment: I moved this RewriteRule to appear above the others in my .htaccess and it seems to be working now. Phew.